# Is there any way to avoid an external microphone from recording?

Tags: android

I'm building an app that records the user's voice, and I would like to know if there is any way to choose which microphone the application is going to use to record the sound.

My target is to mute the external microphone if the user has one, and let the internal microphone, which is embedded on the smartphone, work.

Does AudioManager offers this options?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't want to be _that guy_ but sounds like you first need to read Android docs on audio input, and see whether _AudioManager offers this options_, before seeking for help here.  If you're question is that something is not working, then you should post what you've done so far, so we can help.

Comment: I already read the Audio Manager documentation but I couldn't find the answer for my question, this makes me believe that there is no way to avoid the external microphone from recording, I've been searching all over the internet and I couldn't find any information saying that it is possible, so my last attempt was to answer here.

Comment: Have you found at least a way to get microphone input? Post whatever you have, that'll help us help you.  Usually on device selection APIs always offer a way to iterate through available ones, so you're just probably missing something on your code.